# How to refresh main activity after deleting a list item in another activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview

I have 3 Activities in application, namely ExpenseSummary, AddExpense, ExpenseList.

I am using cursor adapter to populate the Expense List.

Here is code snippet from ExpenseCursorAdapter

```
        Button deleteItem=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.deleteItem);
        deleteItem.setTag(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ExpenseEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ID)));
        final ExpenseTrackerDBHelper db_helper = new  ExpenseTrackerDBHelper(context);

        deleteItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                deleteRecordWithId(itemId);
                cursor.requery();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            private void deleteRecordWithId(String itemId) {
                String selection = ExpenseEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ID + " = ?";
                // Specify arguments in placeholder order.
                String[] selectionArgs = { String.valueOf(itemId) };
                // Issue SQL statement.

                SQLiteDatabase db = db_helper.getWritableDatabase();    
                db.delete(ExpenseEntry.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        });
```

When I try to delete an item it is removed from the list. Though I am not sure if it is getting deleted from database.

Now if click back button which show the EspenseSummary Activity which shows total of all the expenses using following code in on_create method.

```
public void showExpenseTotal(){
  ExpenseTrackerDBHelper mDbHelper = new ExpenseTrackerDBHelper(this);
  SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

  long total_expense = 0;
  Cursor cursor;
  cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(amount) FROM Expenses;", null);
  cursor.moveToFirst();
  total_expense = cursor.getLong(0);
  String total = Long.toString(total_expense); 

  expenseTotal.setText(total.toString()); 
}
```

Update:

```
protected void onResume(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    showExpenseTotal(); 
}
```

This total is not updated. Item deletion is not reflecting in summary page.
Though if I add a new expense the total shown becomes correct.

Please help me here. I am new with Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `onResume()` to update your changes since ExpenseSummary is already created , going back will not call `onCreate()` again.. it will be resumed.

You should learn more about Activity's LifeCycle
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: I have added the code in onResume(). It doesn't seem to be helping. Where I am doing it wrong?

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to call super.onResume().

Answer (score 0):

You have to call

```
adapter.notifydatasetchanged()
```

This notifies all the observers that your data set has changed. Do this in onResume() of your activity.